# Ng Expression not parsing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple piece of ng code here that for some reason will not parse the expressions I'm putting in the front end.
It's displaying as "{{ actionsDueSoon }}".

JS:

```
var module = angular.module('pt_MyActionsController', ['angular-flot']);
module.controller('pt_MyActionsController', ['$scope', '$http', '$rootScope', 'urlTemplateService',
function($scope, $http, $rootScope, urlTemplate) {

    $scope.actionsDueSoon = 0;
    $scope.actionsDue = 0;
    $scope.actionsLate = 0;

    loadRequiresMyResponse();

    function loadRequiresMyResponse() {
           $http.get([REDACTED]).success(function(data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.count; i++) {
                if (data.data[i].RAGStatus == "0") {
                    $scope.actionsDueSoon += 1;
                } else if (data.data[i].RAGStatus == "1") {
                    $scope.actionsDue += 1;
                } else if (data.data[i].RAGStatus == "2") {
                    $scope.actionsLate += 1;
                }
            };

            console.log("Due Soon: " + $scope.actionsDueSoon);
            console.log("Due: " + $scope.actionsDue);
            console.log("Due Late: " + $scope.actionsLate);

        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    };
}
]);
```

I'm adding a simple expression to the html to try and display some of this data but to no avail:

HTML:

```
<li id="liMyActions" class="widget" ng-controller="pt_MyActionsController">
  <div class="handle">My Actions<i class="fa fa-cog right widget-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  <div class="widget-inner">
    {{ actionsDueSoon }}
  </div>
  <div class="widget-settings"></div>
</li>
```

I'm assuming it's something silly as I've very similar code with another controller further down the page.

**I know the data is being retrieved as the console.log's are displaying the expected values.**

Can anyone spot an issue?

Comment: Try to add a dummy variable at the beginning of the controller and display it

Comment: When you said it "will not parse the expressions", what do you see instead inside `<div class="widget-inner"></div>`?

Comment: @Weedoze I've tried that. same result.

Comment: @TewsonSeeoun I's just displaying it as text {{ actionsDueSoon }}

Comment: @Spitfire2k6 You did not mentionned that it was displaying with the brackets... What are the errors in your console ?

Comment: @Spitfire2k6 If even the brackets are not parsed, it's likely that either there's an error in the app (see console) or the app is not running at all.

Comment: Console is clear of errors pertaining to this. It only contains missing media.

Comment: Supply a working code sample, there's no way to debug this otherwise

Comment: This works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/7zLq1gp6/ it must be something not shown causing the error.

Comment: So I'm not sure what's changed. Nothing from what I can see but it's now working. I'm honestly not sure how it happened.

@WilliamB If you'd like to submit your response I'll accept it as the answer.

Comment: I had to remove the angular-flot and urlTemplateService dependencies to get the fiddle to run, so maybe some dependency is missing in your actual codebase causing this error? I don't think I should submit an answer since I'm not really sure what the problem was. Happy to help though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm not sure what's changed. Nothing from what I can see but it's now working.
I'm honestly not sure how it happened.

@William B
If you'd like to submit your response I'll accept it as the answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have this controller `pt_MyActionsController` defined in a module called `pt_MyActionsController`. Maybe this module wasn't declared as a dependency in the root app module?

Comment: This is not the issue. It's set up fine

Comment: That is strange. Could you put a `console.log` just above `$scope.actionsDueSoon = 0;` and see if it's run?